# .val("value") not working as expected in jQuery 1.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, jquery-1.5

I'm using jQuery 1.5.2 to manipulate 2 dropdown selects on a form.  I have a special requirement that if the 'Other' option is selected, both selects must be 'Other'.

## Problem:

my code looks like this

```
$("#Select_One")
    .change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "Other") {
            $("#Select_Two").val("Other");
        }
        else {
            if($("#Select_Two").val() == "Other") {
                $("#Select_Two").val("");
            }
        }
    });

$("#Select_Two")
    .change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "Other") {
            $("#Select_One").val("Other");
        }
        else {
            if($("#Select_One").val() == "Other") {
                $("#Select_One").val("");
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that, rather than enforcing the rule that both fields be 'Other', `$("#Select_Two").val("Other");` just adds or overwrites with the `value="Other"` property on each `<option>` under `#Select_Two`.  Same thing happens with `#Select_One`.

My HTML is from a grails template

```
    <g:select id="Select_One"
              name="Units_One"
              class="Required DropDown"
              from="${Unit_One.values()}"
              optionKey="value_"
              optionValue="${{it.value_}}"
              noSelection="${['': message(code: 'units.no.selection')]}"
     />
     <g:select id="Select_Two"
               name="Units_Two"
               class="Required DropDown"
               from="${Unit_Two.values()}"
               optionKey="value_"
               optionValue="${{it.value_}}"
               noSelection="${['': message(code: 'units.no.selection')]}"
     />
```

What chrome debugger shows me after setting ether field to 'Other' is this...

```
<select name="Units_Two" id='Select_Two" class="Required DropDown">
  <option value="Other">Select Number</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  <option value="Other">1</option>
  etc...
```

The else clause of these functions works just as intended.

---

## Question:

How do I enforce that selecting 'Other' in one field automatically selects 'Other' in the corresponding field?

Comment: [It seems like it works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/7B68C/) Please check that fiddle and post your HTML.

Comment: Its working just fine see http://jsfiddle.net/U75Rw/2/.. I think you've issue with something else

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I have edited my Question to include more of the HTML bits.  Also, thanks for the tips on jsfiddle.  I'll add that to my set of tools.

Comment: Is your HTML generated as you expected from your Grails view?  If so, then something else in your javascript is changing it.  The javascript you posted does not change the value attribute of the option elements.

Comment: Gah! I think my cache must not have been clearing.  the exact code I have up there works like it should now.  I am still a bit confused though because I was getting bad results on EI and Firefox as well.

Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
$("#Select_One").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
        $("#Select_Two option[value='Other']").attr("selected",true);
    }
    else {
        if ($("#Select_Two").val() == "Other") {
            $("#Select_Two").val("");
        }
    }
});

$("#Select_Two").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
        $("#Select_One option[value='Other']").attr("selected",true);
    }
    else {
        if ($("#Select_One").val() == "Other") {
            $("#Select_One").val("");
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: Might want to check out the comment trail; it was resolved yesterday :)